# Use Replace for XML element values containing file paths

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am currently reading a XML but ran into an issue where I need to strip out a file path from an Element value. I have tried wrapping the value in an `IF` statement with `Contains` but that is not working. I read the values into a listbox once the application is done getting the values from the elements through the XML Reader. `nc:DocumentFileControlID` is where I am hitting the file path issue.

XML snippet:

```
<j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="63196917">5583</j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
  <ecf:FilingPartyID>
   <nc:IdentificationID>11333</nc:IdentificationID>
   <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
</ecf:FilingPartyID>
</ecf:DocumentMetadata>
<ecf:DocumentRendition>
 <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
  <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
   <nc:DocumentFileControlID>C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Summons.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
       <nc:BinarySizeValue>29413</nc:BinarySizeValue>
       <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>2</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
    </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
 </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
</ecf:DocumentRendition>
```

C# code using Xml Reader:

```
while (xr.Read())
 {
if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.Name == "nc:DocumentFileControlID")
 {
  fileToSave = xr.ReadElementString();

if (fileToSave.Contains(".pdf") || fileToSave.Contains(".doc"))
  {
  //lbFileName.Items.Add(eventCode + "_" + fileToSave);
  lbFileName.Items.Add(fileToSave);
  fileToSave.Replace("\\", "_");
  }
 }
```

Comment: What was the issue exactly? Anyway, `XmlReader` is for *reading* I suppose. Am I missing something here? or you meant to get a modified value from XML instead of modifying the XML it self?

Comment: @har07 the vendor who wrote one of our applications, allows for the full path in the name convention of a PDF file. In the above XML, `nc:DocumentFileControlID` shows the file path when I only need the items from the last slash forward.